# AWS DynamoDB map attribute number key can not be removed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In Go (Haven't tested with other languages) Removing an attribute from a map with the attribute's key being an int does not work.

*Replication*

```
params := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        Key: //someKey//
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string {
            "#test": aws.String("test"),
        },
        UpdateExpression: aws.String("REMOVE #test.1"),
        TableName: aws.String("someTable"),
}
out, err := db.UpdateItem(params)
if(err != nil){
        fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(*out)
```

The above will emit the error:

```
ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "1", near: ".1"
```

Adding attributes with a number key is no issue, removing them apparently is, is there a way around this/ how should I report this to aws?

Answer (score 0):

You have to substitute the 1 with ExpressionAttributeNames as well, `"#one": aws.String("1")` and then change the UpdateExpression to `aws.String("REMOVE #test.#one")`.